# getBean by name in java configuration file

Tags: java, spring

I have a java configuration file (class with @configuration annotation). It has one method with @Bean annotation and I would like to instantiate this bean based on some arguments. In other words I would like to get a bean by name (passed via argument) and instantiate this bean.

Is it possible to do this in @configuration class?

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Resource
    private Config config;
    @Bean
    public Object application() throws ParseException {
        return new SampleApp(/*get the bean by name*/);
    }
}
```

config contains the argument and I would like to use this argument and get the bean by that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Resource
    private Config config;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Bean
    public Object application() throws ParseException {
        return new SampleApp(
                (appContext.getBean("beanNameFromConfig"));
    }
}
```